# Why didn't Mr Creedy get a scarlet carson?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

During *V for Vendetta*, V gave a scarlet Carson to every single one of his victims he took revenge on, for what they did to Valerie. All of them, except Mr. Creedy.

Why didn't V give him the flower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

V does not leave the roses for everyone that he kills. He reserves them specifically for his victims who once worked at Larkhill Resettlement Camp, as a direct form of revenge for their role in Valerie's imprisonment and death. Prothero was once a guard at the camp, Bishop Lilliman was the chaplain, and Delia worked as a doctor, but Creedy had no connection to Larkhill.

Comment: The high chancellor also gets a rose, but he never worked there.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent The chancellor was the very reason why the camp was created. If anyone deserves a rose, it would be Sutler.

Comment: I don't know, seems kinda an ambiguous criteria...

Comment: Creedy came along after Larkhill, it was his idea to target domestic populations rather than foreign targets

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent The connection is that V grew Scarlet Carsons while at Larkhill. So he gives the roses to the people he knew there. I don't recall how explicit this was in the films, but the graphic novel definitely includes. The flowers are even an important part of how he eventually escapes.